# Import questions to database, facing issue with csv file in cakephp

Tags: php, csv, cakephp, export-to-csv, cakephp-2.3

I am trying to import question(Indian languages like Telugu and Hindi) to database.

To import we are using csv file format but CSV file doesn't support telugu text, When I created a csv file with telugu it's converting text to "????????".

Can we import questions with .xlsx fomat...?
This is my controller file code

```
    public function importcsv()
{
    try
    {
        if ($this->request->is('post'))
        {
            if(is_array($this->request->data['QuestionGroup']['group_name']))
            {
                if(strlen($this->request->data['Iequestion']['subject_id'])>0)
                {
                    $fixed = array('Iequestion' => array('subject_id' => $this->request->data['Iequestion']['subject_id']));
                    $groupName=$this->request->data['QuestionGroup']['group_name'];
                    $filename = null;$extension=null;
                    $extension = pathinfo($this->request->data['Iequestion']['file']['name'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                    if($extension=="csv")
                    {
                        if (!empty($this->request->data['Iequestion']['file']['tmp_name']) && is_uploaded_file($this->request->data['Iequestion']['file']['tmp_name']))
                        {
                            $filename = basename($this->request->data['Iequestion']['file']['name']);
                            move_uploaded_file($this->data['Iequestion']['file']['tmp_name'],APP . DS . 'tmp' . DS . 'csv' . DS . $filename);
                            $this->Iequestion->importCSV(APP . DS . 'tmp' . DS . 'csv' . DS . $filename,$fixed,$groupName,'QuestionGroup');
                            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Questions imported successfully'),'flash',array('alert'=>'success'));
                            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $this->Session->setFlash(__('File not uploaded'),'flash',array('alert'=>'danger'));
                            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Only CSV File supported'),'flash',array('alert'=>'danger'));
                        return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Please Select Subject'),'flash',array('alert'=>'danger'));
                    return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Please Select any Group'),'flash',array('alert'=>'danger'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        $this->Session->setFlash($e->getMessage(),'flash',array('alert'=>'danger'));
        return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check DB encoding

Comment: encode with urf8 your column collate

Comment: It's utf8_general_ci